# Too many values to unpack error in frangi filter

Tags: python, opencv

I receive an error "Too many values to unpack" when running the following code:

```
from skimage.filters import frangi, hessian
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = cv2.imread('test.png')
image= cv2.resize(image,(300,300))
cv2.imshow('im',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3, subplot_kw={'adjustable': 'box-forced'})
k=frangi(image)
ax[0].imshow(k, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[0].set_title('Frangi filter result')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html#frangi), it says that the `image` has to be:

- `image`: (N, M) `ndarray`

  - Array with input image data.

Basically, you can convert the image to grayscale before applying the filter; something like this:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.filters import frangi, hessian

image = cv2.imread('test.png')  # <-- shape: (N, M, C)
image = cv2.resize(image, (300,300))

cv2.imshow('im', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3, subplot_kw={'adjustable': 'box-forced'})
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   # <-- shape: (N, M)
k = frangi(gray_image)
ax[0].imshow(k, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[0].set_title('Frangi filter result')
```

---

This is an MCVE, based on [scikit examples](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_frangi.html):

```py
import cv2
from skimage.data import camera
from skimage.filters import frangi

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('lenna.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
frangi_result = frangi(gray_image)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

ax[0].imshow(image[..., ::-1])  # BGR to RGB
ax[0].set_title('Original image')

ax[1].imshow(gray_image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[1].set_title('Grayscale image')

ax[2].imshow(frangi_result, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[2].set_title('Frangi filter result')

for a in ax:
    a.axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image: frangi output]

Comment: Thank u so much for ur answer,the code ran without any errror.